# Only count null rows when it's unique

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I want to be able to pull data when it either has data or if it's a unique record with null. Is it possible to do this without MAX?

| Name | Class | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Math | 100 |
| Joey | Math | Null |
| Joey | Science | 100 |
| Joey | Science | Null |
| Joey | Science | 95 |

Since Joey only has one Math, it should still be in the query results. On the other hand, since there are two science classes for Joey, the null would be filtered out.

Results should be:

| Name | Class | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Math | 100 |
| Joey | Math | Null |
| Joey | Science | 100 |
| Joey | Science | 95 |

I tried putting a query together, but didn't have much luck:

```
Select distinct Name, Class, Grade,
ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by Name, Class order by Name asc) as RowNum
from Data
Where RowNum = 1
```

This is a very simplified version of a query that pulls in 20 different columns, so I'd like to avoid groups and MAX, if at all possible. I appreciate any help! Thank you.

Comment: What about if there are 3 rows? If you have to do this across multiple columns, what happens if the nulls are in different rows?

Comment: @Charlieface I believe Gordon Linoff already resolved this question, but I wanted to make sure I responded to you, just to make sure I keep all scenarios in mind. Just ensuring I understand your question: Do you mean if, say Joey, had three rows for Science and they were all null? I would like one null row to be returned.

Comment: No, I mean what if there are multiple *non-null* rows, what result do you want? And if you are doing this on multiple columns, say `Grade` and `TotalMarks` where do we take the data from? All on one row ordering by one of the columns, or the `max` of each column, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, but need two important changes:

- You need a subquery to filter by the results of the `row_number()`.
- The window function needs to do what you really want.

My understanding is that you want either all non-`NULL` grades.  Or, if all grades are `NULL`, then return those:

```
select Name, Class, Grade
from (Select d.*,
             rank() over (partition by Name, Class
                          order by (case when grade is not null then 1 else 2 end)
                         ) as seqnum
      from Data d
     ) d
Where seqnum = 1
```